# "SelectedIndex must always be set to a valid value" listpicker issue in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried all the solutions given here on this site but all failed in my case.
Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414624/windows-phone-listpicker-set-selectedindex) didn't solve my problem..please suggest any other solution or explain me why its not working.

I have a listpicker of products and it is binded in code behind like

`listpickerProducts.ItemSourde = <myProductList>`

and the following code is written in **OnNavigateTo** method to change the selectedIndex of this listpicker but it throws an exception because it sets the selectedIndex = -1 always.

```
  listpickerProducts.ItemSourde = <myProductList>

  listpickerProducts.SelectionChanged += listpickerProducts_SelectionChanged;

  listpickerProducts.SelectedIndex = 1; //Here it throws exception : SelectedIndex must always be set to a valid value`
```

my xaml code is as follow :

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="listpickerProducts">
                <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtPID" Text="{Binding PID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtProdName" Text="{Binding ProdName}" FontSize="30"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtUnit" Text="{Binding Unit}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtPID" Text="{Binding PID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtProdName" Text="{Binding ProdName}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtUnit" Text="{Binding Unit}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

listpickerProducts_SelectionChanged event is as follow :

```
    private void listpickerProducts_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {          
       int index = listpickerProducts.SelectedIndex;
     //  MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
       if (index >= 0) 
       { 
         lblUnit.Text = (listpickerProducts.SelectedItem as Products).Unit.ToString();
         lblRateValue.Text = (listpickerProducts.SelectedItem as Products).Rate.ToString();
       }
     }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set the selected index in the this.Loaded event not the OnNavigatedTo. My guess is that you are attempting to set a UI Event prior to the UI being built

Comment: Thank you.I also tried that..but it does not make any difference. :(

Comment: If you're binding, I'd suggest you also bind the selected index.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I am not getting you. I mean, how to bind the selectedIndex?? In xaml code??

Comment: Can you show `listpickerProducts_SelectionChanged`? Shoot in the dark, but I suspect that you put `SelectedItem = null` (or `SelectedIndex = -1`) at the end of this event. When in the next line, you set `SelectedIndex`, the mentioned event is fired and puts `null` to `ListPicker.Item` what causes exception as ListPicker (as error says) must have a valid index >= 0;

Comment: @Romasz I've edited my code..and I'm not setting any selectedIndex in this event.

Comment: Ok, as I've tried there is one more possibility - in your `OnNavigatedTo` - when you set `listpickerProducts.ItemsSource = <myProductList>` - isn't `<myProductList>` empty? On the other side - have you tried to debug?

Comment: @Romasz, <myProductList> is not empty and I've also tried it by debugging the code..it won't allow to go further.

Comment: Can you set a BreakPoint at the beginning of `listpickerProducts_SelectionChanged` - I think it will be fired when you set `SelectedIndex` in `OnNavigatedTo` - debug it step by step and see if there is no problem. And also check if your `<myProductList>` has 2 items as you are setting SelectedIndex as second.

Comment: yes,I've tried it out too. its giving me -1 when the page has been loaded first time..but i want to set my own new index value..why its not allowing??

Comment: @user3734028 Is it possible that you can share simple project with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the exception message itself is very informative. You are setting the selected index when you navigate to the page. At this point, the `ListPicker` may not even loaded. Even if it is loaded, it hasn't finished binding yet. So, it doesn't have any items and index 1 is invalid. You can try a couple of approaches here.

1. Try setting the index in `listpickerProducts.Loaded` event. If that works, you're just good to go.
2. Comment out the line which sets the index. Don't set index at all. Now, run the app and make sure that your `ListPicker` is indeed populated with items. There may be some binding error and the `ListPicker` may have zero items making index 1 invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per the 2nd approach,my listpicker is populating well as i needed..but what i actually want is..whenever I come back to this page..at that time..I am coming with an index value..which i want to set here as the selectedIndex of listpickerProducts.

Comment: As i have specified, its taking -1 everytime when the page is being loaded. Therefore, when i have a new index value to set,it is not allowing me to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It would help you out:

```
private void listpickerProducts_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listpickerProducts.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        int index = listpickerProducts.SelectedIndex;
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            lblUnit.Text = (listpickerProducts.SelectedItem as Products).Unit.ToString();
            lblRateValue.Text = (listpickerProducts.SelectedItem as Products).Rate.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is not in the selectionChanged event..it works fine. But, What I want is, whenever I come to this page,it should allow me to set an index value which I am getting from somewhere else.
I want my listpicker to be selected with the index I want.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that the ListPicker seems to require implementation of Equals in your product object or whathever class is used in the item source. 
Fixed the issue for me.